# Boost Filesystem headers do not compile on Ubuntu LTS 12.04 with GCC 4.8 (C++11)

Tags: ubuntu, boost, c++11, g++

I've just set up a new Linux system, this time with Ubuntu LTS 12.04. Installed GCC 4.8, Boost version is 1.46, which should support `BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION 3`. Yet compilation of just `filesystem.hpp` breaks because of a deleted copy ctor of `boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator`.

Now this of course happens only because I'm compiling Boost 1.46 as C++11, C++03 didn't have deleted functions. Is there a clean fix to get this working? What version of Boost can be compiled as C++11 ?